# Can I hide cells that contain a Vlookup Function but have the function still work?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am working on an Excel project where a user types in a product id number, and the corresponding image appears on a different cell.

To make this work, there is another cell which runs a Vlookup and checks for that id number on a product database, stored in a different sheet.
I then use VBA to output the image onto the correct cell.

Is it possible to hide the cells with the Vlookup function but still have it run when a user changes the cell with the ID number?

Comment: You cannot hide single cells. You can only hide rows or columns on a sheet or the complete sheet.

Comment: The easiest thing to do it put the vlookup somewhere they can't see it, set the font to white on white and protect the range (requires password protecting the sheet as well).  If it's on another tab it's fine.

Comment: You can even hide a complete sheet in such a way that a user will not be able to unhide it via the user interface unless he uses the VBE editor. And that is the sheet you use for our VLOOKUP formula. As you work with VBA anyway why don't you get the right in value with the help of VBA by using `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks for your help. Does this piece of code look good? I am having a little bit of trouble translating the Vlookup into VBA:WorksheetFunction.VLookup(keyCell.Offset(3, 0), Sheets("Product Database").Range(":A2:E5000"), 5, FALSE)

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function like the following one

```
Function getval() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Input") ' sheet used for input
    Set rg = ws.Range("F10")  ' cell with the productid
    
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")  ' sheet with the data
    
    Dim rgData As Range
    Set rgData = wsData.Range("A1:B4")  ' range with the data
    
    getval = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rg, rgData, 2, False)  ' replace the 2 with the column you need
End Function
```

You can test it

```
Sub testit()
    Debug.Print getval
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is very simple using VBA (see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/lock-cell-without-protecting-worksheet/m-p/2360200).  You open the VBA editor and select the Worksheet you want to protect.  Add this code inside the same sheet, and this will automatically "correct" the formulas if someone decides to change them.

```
' protect cells in worksheet, change back if they get modified
' for individual cells separate them by commas like (Range("A1, B1, C1")
' or use ranges

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("H12:O14"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that macros need to be enabled for this to work.  I added it to a spreadsheet I need to protect cell ranges on and it works as expected.  If you type anything other than what exists in the cell already, it automatically changes it back.

Comment: You can "break" this code by Cut & Copy the range resp. cell in question. The code will not restore the formula. ANd afetr you have done that you can, of course, change the formula. Unfortunately I do not know why although the event is triggered

Comment: If you use a named range for a single cell, then the cut / paste just moves the range, and it still works.  If you have a range of values in a named range, then it can be broken.  I tried with a range named "letters" by editing like this: `If Not Intersect(Range("letters"), Target) Is Nothing Then`